# CoffeeScript Encapsulation and Variable Access

Tags: coffeescript

Trying to understand how CoffeeScript instance and class variable works I came with this code (and the results are in the comments).

```
class A
  x: 1
  @y: 2

  constructor: (@z) -> 
    #console.log "const x", x #ReferenceError: x is not defined
    console.log "constructor y", @y #undefined
    console.log "constructor z", @z # = 3 for A and 6 for B

  get: () -> 
    #console.log "get x", x #ReferenceError: x is not defined
    console.log "get y", @y #undefined
    console.log "get z", @z # = 3 for A and 6 for B

  get2: () => 
    #console.log "get2 x", x #ReferenceError: x is not defined
    console.log "get2 y", @y #undefined
    console.log "get2 z", @z # = 3 for A and 6 for B

  @get3: () -> 
    #console.log "get3 x", x #ReferenceError: x is not defined
    console.log "get3 y", @y # = 2
    console.log "get3 z", @z #undefined

  @get4: () => 
    #console.log "get4 x", x #ReferenceError: x is not defined
    console.log "get4 y", @y # = 2
    console.log "get4 z", @z #undefined

class B extends A
  constructor: (@w) ->
    super(@w)

console.log '------A------'
i = new A 3
console.log "i.x", i.x # = 1
console.log "i.y", i.y #undefined
console.log "i.z", i.z # = 6
i.get()
i.get2()
A.get3()
A.get4()
console.log '------B------'
i = new B 6
console.log "i.x", i.x # = 1
console.log "i.y", i.y #undefined
console.log "i.z", i.z # = 6
console.log "i.w", i.w # = 6
i.get()
i.get2()
B.get3()
B.get4()
console.log '------------'
```

There are some strange things happening here:

1. x var
   I was expecting to access it from any method but x var can't be accessed from any method or constructor (ReferenceError). I'm only able to access it from a instance of A or B (i.x). Why is that?
2. @y var
   I was expecting to get @y var value from any method but it has no value in most of places (undefined value, not a ReferenceError exception). @y has value only on @get3 and @get4 (instance methods?). If it is defined, why I can't get its value?
3. @y and @z var
   Both @y and @z are instance variables, but because @z was initialized in the constructor, it has a differentiated behavior. @y is valid on @get3 and @get4 and @z is valid on get and get2. Again, what is happening here?

The thing is that I'm really confused by these behaviors. Is this code correct? So, should I learn more about JS generated by CS?

Tks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In function bodies, `@` refers to `this` and in class definitions, `@` refers to the class itself rather than the prototype.

So in the example above, the definition of `@y` refers to `A.y`, and not `A.prototype.y`. It's tricky to refer to it because of the way `this` is bound in the various ways of defining methods. You can access it using `@y` from methods named `@get` because in this case `this` always refers to `A`.

The definition of `x` refers to `A.prototype.x` and so from your `get` methods you should access it via `@x` in `get1` and `get2`.

As a basic guide, try not to use `@` outside of function bodies and everything will make a lot more sense:

```
class A
  constructor: (@a) ->
  b: 2
  tryStuff: =>
    console.log(@a) #will log whatever you initialized in the constructor
    console.log(@b) #will log 2
```

**EDIT**: you could consider methods defined as `@something` to be static methods of that class, so you can call them with `classname.something()` but as static methods, they can't access any instance variables.

Comment: Great! I think the most important thing is here: "As a basic guide, try not to use @ outside of function bodies and everything will make a lot more sense" True!

Answer (score 9):

To respond to your questions:

1. `x = 1` within the class body would create a variable named `x` within the scope body. But `x: 1` within the class body defines a property `x` on the prototype. If you change `console.log x` to `console.log @x`, then you'll get `1`.
2. Within the class body, `@` points to the class itself. Within the constructor (and in methods called as `instance.method`), it points to the particular instance. Change `console.log @y` to `console.log A.y`, and you'll get `2`. (You can also use `@constructor` to get a reference to the class from the instance, because in JavaScript, the class actually *is* the constructor function.)
3. Since `@` in the constructor points to the instance, you're setting the instance's `z` property to the given value.

And yes, I do recommend understanding the underlying JavaScript—I know it's a bit odd for `@` to have so many different meanings, but it makes a lot of sense once you understand JavaScript's `this` (one of the trickier parts of the language, to be sure). Incidentally, [my book](http://pragprog.com/titles/tbcoffee/coffeescript) has a lot more info on this.

Comment: Tks! And BTW, I have already pre-ordered your book :D Hope to get it soon!